# How to run testng test cases in UNIX/LINUX environment

Tags: java, unix, testing, testng

I am new to automation testing and Testng framework.I am developing my test cases in java and in windows enviroment.I want to run these developed test cases in unix/linux enviroment.Can any one help me out with step by step process of this.Many thanks

@PeterLawrey I have the below pom.xml which I am trying execute on unix

```
    {   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-              instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>ProjTestAutomation</groupId>
      <artifactId>ProjTestAutomation2</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>ProjTestAutomation</name>
      <description>ProjTestAutomation</description>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
         <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
              <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
              </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>ProjestAutomation</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjTestAutomation2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      </dependencies>
     </project>

    }
```

but I am getting below error 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project MDFSureManager: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
        [ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
        [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: TestCustomerResource

Comment: I would run the test from your build system. Do you have `maven` or `ant` e.g. in maven you would run `mvn test`

Comment: Hi Peter,I dont have any idea about maven or ant.That is why I asked for step by step process.Please let me know If you are fully aware of how this can be achieved

Comment: Yes, you follow the guide for maven on how to set it up. Then running it is trivial.

Comment: Oh..ok thank you.I will go through that. In case of any clarifications will contact you.Thanks

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have the below pom.xml which I am trying execute on unix {}

Comment: I suggest you use standard layout. I suspect you are confusing the plugin by having the resources and code being the same directory and then excluding then code.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Lawrey mentioned, use some java build system. Than you are platform independent.

Possible options:

- [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) - very flexible, uses Groovy language for configuration
- [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) - XML declarative configuration, tons of plugins
- [Ivy+Ant](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/)

I personally used standalone Ant (was pain). Than Maven and never looked elsewhere since.

If you want to start with Maven take a look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html. Here is XML how to [integrate it with TestNg](http://testng.org/doc/maven.html).

Getting familiar with some build system is must if you are planning to do serious Java programing and will pay back with enhanced productivity.

Comment: +1 A build system will run the tests for you and much, much more.  It can be pain to setup but once you do it will save you so much time.